# Recognize Specific Characters In a Text

Tags: ios, objective-c

hy
im making an app to help students study better but im having trouble. the app let you make notes between other things,but I need a code that can recognize specific characters in a text for example the user writes in a note "Dolphins ***:*** are cetacean mammals closely..." i need the app to recognize the character ***:*** and also the part thats on the left it needs to be save to use later, as a variable and the part of the right also but as a different variable so I can use them later.
if you can get me the code for that it be great but if possible i preferred a tutorial :)
(the app is for **iPhone** im using **Xcode 5**)

Comment: Read the documentation for `NSString`. There's a whole section of methods for finding text.

Comment: For some random reason, I feel like what he's really looking for is tutorials on how to do OCR, @rmaddy. Or maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
NSArray *stringArray = [yourNSString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSString *leftString = stringArray[0];
NSString *rightString = stringArray[1];
```

EDIT: Just make sure string has the ":" character.

Comment: Careful. This code will crash if the text doesn't have the separator.